# Divisible by 11

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

How many divisors of $11$ are in a $9$ digit number containing distinct digits from $\{1,2,...9\}$ (no repetitition)

**My attempt** : Let $e$, $o$ denote sum of digits at even and odd places.

$e+o=1+2...9=45$

$|e-o|=0,11,22,33...$

Also,

$10\leqslant e\leqslant 30$

$15\leqslant o\leqslant 35$
As $e$ and $o$ are natural numbers, we see that only possible case is :

$|e-o|=11$

Either $e=28,o=17$ OR $e=17,o=28$

Let $e=a_2+a_4+a_6+a_8$

$o=a_1+a_3+a_5+a_7+a_9$

The total number of divisors are $(\alpha+\beta) 5! 4!$ where those two variables are solutions for two conditions obtained earlier.

What is the best strategy to find their number of solutions manually? I tried to related it with multinomial but that is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $e$ is so close to the limit in both cases, enumerating by hand is not too hard.  The highest $e$ can be is $30$ and for the first case you need it to be $28$.  Starting with $9876$, we need to subtract $2$, and the only choices are $9874$ and $9865$.  In the other case, the minimum $e$ can be is $10$ and you need $17$.  There are more possibilities, but still within hand work being systematic.  I find $1259,1268,1349,1358,1367,1457,2348,2357,2456$ for nine.

You could do this with stars and bars, but the numbers are small enough that hand work is easier.

Comment: Okay... how could I have not used brute force? But minimum of e is 10. I can do it on my own.But what is stars and bars?

Comment: How do I convince myself that I cannot find more solutions for second case?

Comment: I found 8. I am sure there are more.

Comment: Oops, when I thought about $e=17$ I thought it had five terms.  [Stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a standard way to solve these.  You want to partition the $17$ into four increasing pieces.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it with that method. We would use inclusion/exclusion?